# How can I do injection inside a method body?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
class Foo {
    @Resource(lookup=url)
    private DataSource ds;
}
```

But the `url` is dynamic and will be loaded inside a method body:

```
class Bar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = xxx;
        DataSource ds;
        //How to inject the datasource using Annotation?
    }
}
```

I know how to use context lookup. I wish to know if there is any annotated way to inject.

Comment: Could you inject a lookup/factory bean that determines the dynamic URL?

Comment: I think this is impossible by annotations, it doesn't make sense, why do you need to do so? create a factory class and get the ds whenever you want with a simple method call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is you can't. There is no way for the code that performs the injection to lookup a local variable of a method. A class field on the other hand is accessible using class inspection methods available in the core java API.

Additionally, an annotation parameter can only be a constant expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Koin](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin) service locator for that purpose. It supports local variables injection inside method.